# Sony Vegas Pro 12 - After rending problems - It leaves black spaces in the video

Tags: video, editing, rendering, sony-vegas

The thing is that the whole video's format is "lying down". Which means that the width is longer than the height.
So far so good!

But then I want to add some videos that I filmed with my phone. And this video is "standing up". You know, the height is longer than the width.

Everything looks good on the timeline. But after I've rendered it and watched the video it just left black empty spaces where those "standing" phone videos should be!

I have added other phone videos which "lays down" and those works flawlessly!

What should I do to make my "standing" videos work?
I've search for answers everywhere and tried everything! :(

Answer (score 0):

Your two definitions should be **Landscape** = 'laying down' & **Portrait** = 'standing up'.

Rule #1 for video is never use portrait, as everybody watches in landscape.

Your only solutions are to shrink to fit, which is what you've done, leaving black borders; or crop & zoom, effectively chopping off the top & bottom of the picture, so the rest fills the screen.

See [The Magic of Crop, Pan, Zoom, and Rotate](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/the_magic_of_crop_pan_zoom_and_rotate) on the Sony site

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I've already tried these solutions. But it still won't render my "portrait" videos.

And of course I know not to film in the "portrait" style. But this is a family video so. ^^

Comment: There are only 2 choices if it was shot in portrait - black stripes down the sides, or top & bottom missing so it fills the screen. There is no third option... well, unless you want everything really really stretched ;-)